# Convergence of series implies convergence of product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n$ is a positive sequence, then the product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)$$
converges iff the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$
converges as well.

Any hints please ?

Comment: Hint: comparison with $\sum_n \ln(1+a_n)$ might help..

Comment: If you are multiplying numbers that are greater than 1, are you going to converge to a real number?  If the series converges, by the n'th term test, you know the limit of $a_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ must be 0...What does that mean for the product if $a_n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Thank you guys. I will see if I can prove it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following inequality: $(1+x)\le e^x$

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+a_n)\le\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{a_n}=e^{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n}$

As $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges the asked products also converges.

Comment: Thank you, that hint was also in the book but I wasn't sure why it might help. You made it very clear!